Почему может не работать авторизация в API СДЭК
Я отправляю запрос на авторизацию в API СДЭК
https://api.edu.cdek.ru/v2/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=E_&client_secret=P_
В ответ приходит 401 код
По какой причине так происходит?
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "No such account secure"
}


Вы в курсе, что светить данные для подключения к API - мягко говоря небезопасно?) Рекомендую вам удалить вопрос и создать его по новой без указания оных

Лучше обратиться в техническую поддержку и изучить документацию https://api-docs.cdek.ru/29923849.html

В ЛК недавно висело уведомление, что надо ключи API обновить. Не пробовали?

Не знаю по какой причине, но у них на данный момент не работает тестовая среда. Отправить подобный запрос с боевыми ключами, но не на "api.edu.cdeck", а на "api.cdeck.ru" получилось.
